# Are Lorialets real or fictional mythological creatures?

Tags: source-request

I've been playing a game that uses a lot of mythological creatures, vampires, sphinxes, kitsune, tengu, minotaurs, etc.

But then they used Lorialets. The only easy source on it that cites things, is [a Wikimonde article](https://plus.wikimonde.com/wiki/Lorialet), whatever that is, which itself cites [this](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/etudfr/1996-v32-n1-etudfr1081/036013ar.pdf) scholarly-looking French PDF about Gargantua and Pantagruel? Can't find "Lorialet" in there?

Other [sources](https://writinginmargins.weebly.com/home/lorialets-and-mooncalves), say that lorialets come from the anonymous chapbooks that were the inspiration for the more famous [Gargantua and Pantagruel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargantua_and_Pantagruel) of François Rabelais.

Is there page-number-and-line style confirmation that *that* fictional work was the origin of lorialets? Or is there an even older source?

Comment: Which game? You should add all the relevant information.

Comment: Have you checked *[La grande encyclopédie des fées](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Grande_Encyclop%C3%A9die_des_f%C3%A9es)*? They appear there...

Comment: @MardukTrimegistus - Do I... Have to buy that? ... And how is the game important? Not that I can remember which game it is... It's just how I found out the idea exists. It's not like it's the source.

Comment: by indicating the game we may confirm how notable the subject is. The game itself could also be a lead to another source, as sometimes developers disclose the myths that inspired the game. History without sources is pointless.